# NamedQuery cannot be found

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I try to execute a namedQuery from the entity `Item` but it results in an error that says that the namedQuery can't be found.

I also tried to get the other namedQuery's but they could also not be found.

The entity with the named query.

```
    @Entity
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Item.getAll", query = "select a from Item as a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Item.count", query = "select count(a) from Item as a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByDescription", query = "select a from Item as a where a.description = :descriptions")
    })
    public class Item implements Comparable, Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="email")
        private User seller;

        private Category category;
        private String description;

        @OneToOne
        private Bid highest;

        public Item(User seller, Category category, String description) {
            this.seller = seller;
            this.category = category;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Item() {

        }

(Getters and setters)
```

Where i try to find the namedQuery from Item.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("auctionPU");    

public List<Item> findByDescription(String description) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Item.findByDescription", Item.class);
             q.setParameter("descriptions", description);
             List<Item> a = q.getResultList();
            em.close();
            return a;
        }
        catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: post persistence.xml

Comment: You did it, forgot to add the Enity to the persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

This error is displayed when you configuration is not corrent .What are you using spring boot or spring???
It seems that you're not scanning the package where you're named query resides, you scan

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="your_base_package_of_model_pojo.**"/>
```

OR

In **spring boot**

Add

```
@EntityScan("your_base_package_of_model_pojo")
```

to your configuration class